# Understanding function `tailp` in Common Lisp

Tags: lisp, common-lisp, sbcl, clisp

While looking through the "Common Lisp Quick Reference" by Bert Burgemeister, I stumbled over `tailp`.

First, I misunderstood the definitions of this function. And I tried:

```
(tailp '(3 4 5) '(1 2 3 4 5))
```

But it returned

```
NIL
```

CLTL2 says, `tailp` is true **iff** the first argument is any `(nthcdr n list)` with existing `n`.

```
(nthcdr 2 '(1 2 3 4 5))
;; (3 4 5)
```

I further tried:

```
(tailp '(3 4 5) '(1 2 3 4 5))
;; NIL - and I would expect: T following the definition above.

(tailp '() '(1 2 3 4 5))
;; T
(tailp '5  '(1 2 3 4 . 5))
;; T
```

Until I tried (and then understood `tailp` looks for `cdr` of `l` which share even the same address):

```
(defparameter l '(1 2 3 4 5 6))
(tailp (nthcdr 3 l) l)
;; T
```

But then I had my next question:

```
For what such a function is useful at all?
```

Wouldn't be a function more useful which looks whether a sublist is part of a list? (Or *looks like* a part of a list, instead that it has to share the same address?)

Remark:

Ah okay slowly I begin to understand, that maybe that this is kind of a `eq` for `cdr` parts of a list ... Kind of ... "Any `cdr`-derivative of given list `eq` to the first argument?".

But maybe someone can explain me in which situations such test is very useful?

## Remark:

In a long discussion with @Lassi [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60253743/9690090), we found out:

**Never Use `tailp` On Circular Lists!**

Because the behavior is undefined (already in SBCL problematic).
So `tailp` is for usage on non-circular lists.

Comment: When the hyperspec says that some things are "same", but doesn't mention under what test, `EQL` is the default. `TAILP` doesn't seem like an especially useful test. A quick grep of my installed quicklisp dists shows [cl-yacc](https://github.com/jech/cl-yacc/blob/master/yacc.lisp#L885) as the only user. From a quick glance over the code, it seems like it gets two cons-cells (`OP1-TAIL` and `OP2-TAIL`) from the same list (the grammar precedence), and uses `TAILP` to check if `OP2-TAIL` is a tail of the cdr of `OP1-TAIL`, which would mean that `OP1` came first in the precedence list.

Comment: Thank you, @jkliski! Ah, I should have come to the idea to grep for it in the lisp source codes which I have! - Thank you for the hint - `same` == `EQL` in the lisp explanations and definitions. Okay ... `TAILP` could then serve as a precedence/successor test within lists ... since it looks directly into he loci, it might then be more performant than other constructed tests, isn't it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The basic purpose of `tailp` is to check whether there is list structure shared. This means whether the *cons cells* are the same (which means `EQL` as a predicate) - not just the content of the cons cells.

One can also check if an item is in the last `cdr`:

```
CL-USER 87 > (tailp t '(1 2 3 4 . t))
T

CL-USER 88 > (tailp nil '(1 2 3 4 . nil))
T

CL-USER 89 > (tailp nil '(1 2 3 4))
T

CL-USER 90 > (tailp #1="e" '(1 2 3 4 . #1#))
T
```

This is one of the rarely used functions in Common Lisp.

Comment: True, I first also tried around with numbers and symbols. But it is a little bit misleading. Because it works with your examples only because `nil`, `t` and all numbers and all symbols have by definition only one physical representation/address. e.g. this `(tailp "e" '("a" "b" "c" "d" . "e"))`
` gives `NIL`.

Comment: @Gwang-Jin Kim: no, there can be multiple objects of the same number value. The test EQ can be false while EQL can be true for numbers. The default sameness predicate is EQL which treats numbers and characters special. Your example works if the "e" is actually the same object.

Comment: yes, true ... I made once for myself a list for equality                            ;;   same symbols? (share the same adress?)                  eq
;;   same type & same case character/number?                 eql
;;   same number (mathematical sense, type insensitive)      =
;;   same case strings, list of equal objects (vec/obj eq!)  equal
;;   same objects (also vectors), case-insensitive string    equalp    - strings begin to be "same" when using `equal`.

Comment: Oh what is this kind of notation. I saw it when creating circular lists. Kind of address reference, isn't it?

Comment: @Gwang-JinKim:  That's used for reading and printing s-expressions, where objects are shared in the structure. See: `*print-circle*`.

Comment: Thank you! - I think now we understood `tailp` so far ;) . Thank you for your contributions!

Answer (score 4):

Here is a case where `tailp` is useful:

```
(defun circular-list-p (l)
  (and (consp l)
       (tailp l (rest l))))
```

A couple of notes.

This terminates in all cases: `tailp` is allowed not to terminate on circular lists if the first argument is not a tail of the second (ie there's no requirement for it to check circularity), but it must terminate if the first argument *is* a tail of the second.  But, if the list is circular, that's exactly what we check for here, so it terminates.  (I was confused about this for a while).

The `consp` check is so `(circular-list-p nil)` is false: I think this is pragmatically the useful choice although you a pedant might argue that `nil` is circular.

Comment: This won't work if `l` has a circular sublist after one or more initial elements. E.g. `(circular-list-p (list* 1 2 3 (let ((sub (list 4 5 6))) (setf (cdr (last sub)) sub))))`

Comment: Detailed exploration of `tailp` for circular lists: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60253743/6272277

Comment: @Lassi: yes, I'd not call such a list circular though: I'd say it has a circular tail or something like that.  However I don't know whether there is standard terminology around this and mine probably is not standard if there is.

Comment: _Circular tail_ is a nice term. Common Lisp considers any list with a circular tail to be circular itself: "circular list n. a chain of conses that has no termination because some cons in the chain is the cdr of a later cons." I don't know whether this is the standard definition more widely, but it is probably the most useful one. Is there an application that would only require detecting a particular cycle but not others?

Comment: According to that definition, the empty list `()` is not a circular list, since it has no conses. Though it would make for a fun mathematical problem :) There's probably a standard definition in graph theory. According to the Wikipedia and MathWorld _cyclic graph_ pages, they don't consider an empty graph cyclic since it doesn't have any vertices through which a cycle could be made, though this is not stated clearly. However, it would seem that an empty graph is considered an _acyclic graph_.

Comment: @Lassi: I don't know enough graph theory to know the right terms but I'd certainly like to be able to distinguish between a structure where each cons was the cdr of exactly one cons (which I'd call 'circular'), one which contains one or more cycles but which may be less simple (this is what the spec calls 'circular', which I think I'd call 'cyclic'), and one which doesn't but where one or more conses are the cdrs of more than one other cons which I think I'd call a DAG which is not a tree.

Comment: You could cover the first two cases with a function `(length-cycle xs) => length-of-non-repeating-part; length-of-repeating-part`. That might be good for a standard library. You can only detect one cycle algorithmically in a list, since the algorithm will get stuck in that cycle during traversal. Your third case requires traversing the `car`s of some conses, so it's not clear how to do it in a standard library function.

Comment: @Lassi: I need to think about this some more (and SE comments are the wrong place to talk about it as they'll get pruned), but I think I've convinced myself that, because the cdr of a cons can point at at most one object, a list, considered as a chain of cdrs (so ignoring cars) can only *have* one cycle at most: as you walk down the conses, each cdr either points at something not a cons, at a new cons, or at a cons in its own history.

Answer (score 3):

I'm pretty sure the answer to `(tailp '(3 4 5) '(1 2 3 4 5))` can be both `t` and `nil` as a smart compiler might do `(tailp '#1=#(3 4 5) '(1 2 . #1#))` to reduce memory footprint. Quoted stuff are immutable literals so why not use the same memory twice?

Here is how `tailp` is working:

```lisp
(defparameter *tail* (list 3 4 5))
(defparameter *larger* (list* 1 2 *tail*))
(defparameter *replica* (copy-list *larger*))

(tailp *tail* *replica*) ; ==> nil
(tailp *tail* *larger*)  ; ==> t
```

Since `copy-list` creates new cons for each element in a list it will share 
nothing but the empty list with any other list. It is unique.

`*larger*` has been made with a common tail with `*tail*` and thus `(tailp *tail* *larger*)` will be `t`.

It's important that it compares the arguments as same objects. Since the tail does not need to be a list it compares with `eql`. When comparing if stuff look the same you use `equal` so `tailp` is more specific than that. It has to be pointer equal (`eq`) or `eql` atomic value.

So where do you use this? I'm thinking a functional data structure where you typically reuse shared structure. `tailp` might be used to identify a subtree of a parent. It's basically a more performant version of this:

```lisp
(defun my-tailp (needle haystack)
  (cond ((eql needle haystack) t)
        ((atom haystack) nil)
        (t (my-tailp needle (cdr haystack)))))
```

Comment: Thank you, @Sylwester! Longer answer to your answer added as new answer! (below or above ...) ;)

Answer (score 2):

@Sylwester:

Thank you, @Sylwester!

I recently read in Edi Weitz's book about tail wagging a list:

```
(defparameter *list* (list 'a 'b 'c 'd))
(defparameter *tail* (cdddr *list*))
```

This names the car of the last cons cell of the list as `*tail*` - and now, one can add to it a new element and rename the new last car of the last cons cell of the list `*tail*`.

```
(setf (cdr *tail*) (cons 'e 'nil) 
      *tail*       (cdr *tail*)) 
;; (E)
```

Now the list is:

```
*list* 
;; (A B C D E)
```

and one can add via `setf` further things to `*tail*` without having to traverse the list again. (So improves performance. But with a warning of course, because this is a destructive action).

Perhaps, if one would name a list like you did:

```
(defparameter *my-new-tail* '(F G H))
```

and `tail wagg` it to the end of the new list

```
(setf (cdr *tail*) *my-new-tail*
      *tail* (cddr *my-new-tail*))
```

Ah or alternatively:

```
(defparameter *tail-of-my-new-tail* (cddr *my-new-tail*))
;; and then
(setf (cdr *tail*) *my-new-tail*
      *tail*       *tail-of-my-new-tail*)
```

Then

```
(tailp *my-new-tail* *list*)
```

- would be the test, whether this procedure was done correctly
- would also be a test, whether I added a new tail in addition to `*my-new-tail*` or not or if `*my-new-tail*` was the last tail which has been tail wagged to `*list*` or not ...
- therefore `tailp` would be a quite useful test in the context of tail wagging ...
- or like you said, if an implementation uses then tail wagging for performance reasons, (and perhaps keeping track of the tails of the lists constantly) in this context, the implementation could use `tailp` as a test whether a given list contributes to another list as the recently added tail ...

This just came into my thoughts, when reading your answer, @Sylwester! (I didn't realize this while reading about tail wagging in the book - (which is by the way a super useful one!) Thank you that you answered!

Comment: Queues can implemented like that, see e.g. the small *Queues* section in http://norvig.com/paip/auxfns.lisp

Comment: Thank you for the nice link @coredump! I also now saw in Edi Weitz's book that ĥe mentions `tailp` for exactly such purposes ... and he recommends `ldiff` for extracting the part of the list `(ldiff *list* *tail*)` which is the non-common part between *list* and *tail*. I should have searched in his and Norvig's book first :D .