# Concatenate Lists and Return Result into First Argument

Tags: list, functional-programming, append, concatenation, common-lisp

I am wondering what is the most efficient (algrotihmically) and readable way of doing something like this in Common Lisp:

```
(setq result-list (append result-list small-list))
```

That is, is there something like `(append-destructively result-list small-list)` that would make sure that `result-list` contains the concatenated list?

I am doing this to improve readability, but is it a good idea when it comes to (functional) programming practices?

Comment: Alexandria has modify macros `APPENDF` and `NCONCF`. You could also define them yourself easily with `DEFINE-MODIFY-MACRO`.

Comment: I have never heard of `DEFINE-MODIFY-MACRO`. Is that Common Lisp at large or some implementation-specific thing?

Comment: It's Common Lisp: [CLHS](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/m_defi_2.htm)

Answer (score 5):

If you have to do it over and over again on the same list,
`tail-wagging` might be the best solution (which I learned from Edi Weitz's book):

```
(defparameter *l* (list 'a 'b 'c 'd 'e 'f))
```

give the last cons-cell of `*l*` a name

```
(defparameter *tail* (last *l*))
```

now, `(cdr *tail*)` is the last element of the list: `'()`.
let's say you want to add `(list 'g 'h 'i)` to its end.
assign (`setf`) it to `(cdr *tail*)` which is the last `cons`-cell: `'()` of the list `*l*`,
and reassign (`setf`) the new last cons element to *tail*.

```
(setf (cdr *tail*) (list 'g 'h 'i)
      *tail*       (last *tail*))
```

now, `*l*` is mutated to contain the second list.
and `*tail*` names the last `cons` cell of this new list.

```
*l*
;; (a b c d e f g h i)
*tail*
;; (i)
```

The next time, when `*tail*` has to be extended by a list, you don't have to traverse all the list again, but can just assign to `cdr` of `*tail*` the to-be-appended-list and then the original list will be modified.

by the way, I stumbled over `tail-wagging` when contemplating over [`tailp`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50542453/understanding-tailp-in-common-lisp)

Comment: May I suggest to move explanations outside of comments? they render as grey text and you miss markdown formatting.

Comment: "tail-wagging" (never heard this one before) aka "top-down list construction" aka "difference lists". :)

Comment: Could you please cite which the title of Edi Weitz's book?

Comment: @gsl Common Lisp Recipes http://weitz.de/cl-recipes/

Answer (score 4):

The [destructive `append` is called `nconc`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_nconc.htm).

Note, however, that you *still* need to do

```
(setf result-list (nconc result-list small-list))
```

because if `result-list` is `nil`, then `(nconc result-list small-list)`
is `small-list` and `result-list` is unmodified.

Another issue to be aware of is that both `nconc` and `append` are
*linear* in `result-list` length, so this is *not* a very good way to
store a lot of data.

Answer (score 3):

Looking at your question, I’m going to guess at what you want and make some hints for if you want to repeatedly extend a list but don’t want to have to scan it again and again.

If you are in a loop you can use `collect`, `append`, or `nconc`

```
(defun nconcat (lists)
  (loop for list in lists nconc list))
```

If you want to do this in a more general setting the idea is to keep track of the end of the list so that appending needs only to scan the short list. Example:

```
(defun nconcat (lists)
  (let* ((result-ref (list nil))
         (end result-ref))
    (mapc
      (lambda (list)
        (setf (cdr end) list
              end (last end)))
      lists)
    (cdr result-ref)))
```